# How to set Click Listener on a text view in side a viewFlipper in Android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

In my sample news application I have a view Flipper that display news title, you can see XML code of the ViewFlipper below.

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/pushFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#90333333"
        android:flipInterval="4000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        >

    </ViewFlipper>
```

Dynamically I add TextViews to this ViewFlipper in order to display the news title in animated form. Here is the code where I add TextViews to the Flipper.

Now, the issue I am facing is how to set listener on the dynamic TextViews, that I could display the appropriate news descriptionin new Activity of the title that has been displayed on the textview. Please help me in this respect, your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pushFlipper = ((ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.pushFlipper));
            pushFlipper.startFlipping();
try
            {
                RSSdata = new RSSHandler();
                for (int i = 2; i < RSSdata.getTitle().size(); i++)
                {
                    TextView tvNewsRSS = new TextView(this);
                    tvNewsRSS.setText(RSSdata.getTitle().get(i).toString());
                    tvNewsRSS.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    tvNewsRSS.setTextSize(14);
                    tvNewsRSS.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                    pushFlipper.addView(tvNewsRSS);

                }     
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813108/listener-for-viewflipper-widget-flipping-events You can get index of child easily

Comment: Can you explain your issue better? do you want to implements a listener in the dynamic text to do what?

Comment: The textviews display news titles, by clicking on the textView I want to display news description of the displaying news title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solution can be getting newsId on click of item from textview tag and then using this newsId in next activity to fetch and show appropriate news.

Code:

```
try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TextView tvNewsRSS = new TextView(this);
            tvNewsRSS.setText(RSSdata.getTitle().get(i));
            tvNewsRSS.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            tvNewsRSS.setTextSize(14);
            tvNewsRSS.setTag(RSSdata.getId().get(i));
            tvNewsRSS.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            tvNewsRSS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newsId = v.getTag().toString();

                    // Pass this newsId to next activity via intent putExtra.

                }
            });
            pushFlipper.addView(tvNewsRSS);

        }     
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Dear I cordially appreciate your help and thanks for your time.