# How to capture the flip event for ViewFlipper

Tags: android, listener, viewflipper

I've a ViewFlipper component that is flipping automatically, and I want to handle the event in wich the component does a transition between the current View and the next. Is it possible?

Thanks.

```
mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
mViewFlipper.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(this);
mViewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

And this is the log:

02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): Process: com.idiadasample, PID: 7961 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.idiadasample/com.idiada.activity.ViewFlipperActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.animation.Animation.setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener)' on a null object reference 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.animation.Animation.setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener)' on a null object reference 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at com.idiada.activity.ViewFlipperActivity.onCreate(ViewFlipperActivity.java:89) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 02-16 14:27:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): ... 10 more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add animation and listen to animation events as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813108/listener-for-viewflipper-widget-flipping-events):

```
viewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
});
```

Set animation:

```
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
         R.anim.fade_in));
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
         R.anim.fade_out));
```

Comment: Hi, tanks for your reply. If I do that, I've NullPointerException because getAnimation() returns null, how should I initialize it?

Comment: It is still returning null O_o

Comment: Do you set the animation **before** you add the listener? @rlopezo

Comment: Yes :$ With your code I am setting the property InAnimation and OutAnimation, but no the Animation.

Comment: I will need to see more code and error stack trace @rlopezo. Please add your code and LogCat to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71022/discussion-between-marcus-and-rlopezo).

Answer (score 0):

I have extended `ViewFlipper` to do just that.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class DecentViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper implements View.OnLayoutChangeListener {

    public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
        onViewFlipperFlippedListener.onViewFlipperFlipped(view, getDisplayedChild());
    }

    public interface OnViewFlipperFlippedListener {
        void onViewFlipperFlipped(View childView, int index);
    }

    public DecentViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DecentViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private static final String TAG = DecentViewFlipper.class.getSimpleName();
    private OnViewFlipperFlippedListener onViewFlipperFlippedListener = null;

    public void setOnViewFlipperFlippedListener(@NonNull OnViewFlipperFlippedListener listener){
        if (listener == null) throw new IllegalStateException("OnViewFlipperFlippedListener can not be null");
        if (getChildCount() != 0) {
            DecentViewFlipper flipper = (DecentViewFlipper) getCurrentView().getParent();
            flipper.addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't use setOnViewFlipperFlippedListener before you have added at least one View to the "+TAG);
        }
        onViewFlipperFlippedListener = listener;
    }

    public OnViewFlipperFlippedListener getOnViewFlipperFlippedListener() {
        return onViewFlipperFlippedListener;
    }

}
```